# How can i get a row with a latest date where my dates is in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My tables:

```
LoanItemCode    Quantity    ItemDesc    ItemWeight  Karat   
JAR002                 1     Ring           1.60    18      
JAR003                 6     dh             7.00    18

ContractID  EffectiveDate
    60       2016-10-12
    61       2016-10-12
    62       2016-10-13
    63       2016-10-13
```

I Want to see this output:

```
LoanItemCode    Quantity    ItemDesc    ItemWeight  Karat   EffectiveDate
JAR002              1          Ring        1.60       18      2016-10-12
JAR003              6           dh         7.00       18      2016-10-13
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT  LoanItemCode ,Quantity, ItemDesc, ItemWeight, ISNULL(ItemKarat,0) as 'Karat', MAX(EffectiveDate) 
FROM tblLoanContract 
    LEFT JOIN tblLoanItemDetails 
        LEFT JOIN tblLoanItem 
            LEFT JOIN tblItemType 
            ON tblLoanItem.ItemTypeID = tblItemType.ItemTypeID 
        ON tblLoanItemDetails.LoanItemID = tblLoanItem.LoanItemID 
    ON tblLoanContract.ContractID = tblLoanItemDetails.LoanContractID 
WHERE ItemStatusID = 5
-My code
```

Comment: what's the connection between the 2 tables?

Comment: Ive got a table that connects to 2 tables as you can see in my code

Comment: there are 4 tables in your code. Please edit your question to include the other tables as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 3 problems.

1. Your join syntax is incorrect. The `ON` portion of the join must stay with the `JOIN` portion.
2. You are using an aggregate on one of several fields without using grouping. Once you us an aggregate function like `max()`, all other fields must also use an aggregate (e.g. `min()`, `sum()`) or be included in a `GROUP BY` clause.
3. You haven't added an alias to your effective date. `Max()` will result in an unnamed column.

An additional suggestion is to use table aliasing in your joins. I find it makes the join syntax more legible and also easier to understand what table fields are coming from when there are multiple join tables.

Does this work? If not you will have to provide some more details about the other 2 tables.

```
SELECT  lid.LoanItemCode, lid.Quantity, lid.ItemDesc, lid.ItemWeight,
    ISNULL(lid.ItemKarat,0) as 'Karat', MAX(lc.EffectiveDate) EffectiveDate
FROM tblLoanContract lc
    LEFT JOIN tblLoanItemDetails lid
        ON lc.ContractID = lid.LoanContractID 
    LEFT JOIN tblLoanItem li
        ON lid.LoanItemID = li.LoanItemID 
    LEFT JOIN tblItemType it
        ON li.ItemTypeID = it.ItemTypeID 
WHERE ItemStatusID = 5    --I'm not sure what table this comes from so no table alias here
GROUP BY lid.LoanItemCode, lid.Quantity, lid.ItemDesc, lid.ItemWeight,
    ISNULL(lid.ItemKarat,0)
ORDER BY lid.LoanItemCode;
```